# selenium remote webdriver screenshot captures colours incorrectly

Tags: c#, selenium, remotewebdriver

I am taking a screenshot of a Remote WebDriver and as you can see by the image, the colours are not right. On many web pages there is a lot of black, so I can't even read the text. The code is as follows.

```
Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
ss.SaveAsFile(file + ".png", ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
```

Any ideas please? Windows 8.1 by the way. Visual Studio 15.5.7, Selenium 3.9.1

[image]

Comment: this looks like you need to ask it on retrocomputing SE. [here is a hint](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=394) that setting a different color depth may help, but no idea where to configure that: "problem solved by changing color depth to 24"

Comment: Which driver and version are you using?

Comment: @Florent B. I just tried this with a different web driver (chromedriver 2.27) and it works fine. So it looks like it's the driver I was using which is a remote driver based on Gecko 0.15. Unfortunately I have no control over the driver used for this project.

Answer (score -1):

I just tried this with a different web driver (chromedriver 2.27) and it works fine. So it looks like it's the driver I was using which is a remote driver based on Gecko 0.15